# About proper forums for the Netherlands work visa

Tags: support

I am asking about the name of some internet forums for asking:

- Questions about finding a proper job in the Netherlands (for the Netherlands working visa)

I am asking this question for one of my friends who is a mechanical engineer (38-year-old Iranian man with a bachelor's degree) and work experience (management) with companies active in the oil industry.

This question is asked [here](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/21510/about-proper-forums-for-the-netherlands-work-visa?noredirect=1#comment35237_21510) and referred to this forum:

[image]